# Difficulty disabling magento extension

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to disable a Magento cache extension called m-turbo but it keeps appearing in the menu. I have gone to the file `Artic_MTurbo.xml` in `app/etc/modules` and changed `<active>true</active>` to `<active>false</active>`. Is there something else that I need to/should/could do. I thought this was the "way" to disable an extension.

Magento ver. 1.7.0.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you edit the xml's your need to clear the cache in the admin menu, I personally flush the cache too (button in the cache menu right top).

If that doesn't work try renaming the app/etc/modules/Artic_MTurbo.xml to Artic_MTurbo.xml.old or something like that so magento doesn't load it, and repeat the above, clearing the cache.

Answer (score 1):

What junke said is right!
You can do one of these-
1. Are you trying to disable the extension in admin html by going to "system"->"configuration"->"advanced"? if not, this is the first way.
Remember to save config after your changes.
2. Go to index management and reindex selecting all the files. Flush both "magento cache" and "cache storage" from cache management.

Comment: In point 2, I think you mean cache management not index management ;)